# Why is Eclipse 'Clean Up' complaining about ambiguous references?

Tags: java, eclipse

I ran the 'Clean Up' option in Eclipse, with many Java files selected. I got a couple of problems that it couldn't resolve, that looked like this:

```
Problem while Organize Imports: foo.java contains ambiguous references. User interaction required.
```

I don't see any obvious problem with the import statements in that file; what is causing this?

Comment: (You know you can answer the question at the same time you post it, right?)

Comment: I did not know that - next time I'll scroll down more. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My comment header for a method claimed it threw an exception that didn't match what the method really threw; something like this:

```
/**
 * Gets JSON object
 * 
 * @return JSON object
 * @throws ParseException
 */
public JSONObject getRawJson() throws JSONException {
    return this.rawJson;
}
```

Note that the comment lists `ParseException`, but the method actually throws `JSONException`.

Once I fixed the comment header to match, the file cleaned up fine.